# Film within a film dinosaur movie in Scarecrow and Mrs King

Tags: object-identification

I remember watching the spy series Scarecrow and Mrs King in the 80's.

A few times during the series there was like a dinosaur film being shown on TV screen, big lizards fighting each other.

It wasn't one million years BC but seemed the same kind , I've looked at odd clips of "creature features" on YouTube but never identified.

Was it something they just invented for the Scarecrow series?
I never saw the first few episodes so possibly I missed out on a running gag thing

Comment: Any idea which episodes it was seen in?

Comment: It was in different episodes scattered throughout the series, it appeared to be the same dinosaur movie - in colour! A few times it would show her on the phone or looking out the window at odd activity at a neighbours house, every time this happened you would get a few seconds of a sound muted dinosaur film on Mrs King's TV. I spotted this by accident in late eighties and always wondered what  she had been watching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia identifies it as [The Valley of Gwangi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Valley_of_Gwangi) although I've (personally) yet to find a single instance of it playing.

Comment: I never thought of just trying wiki, was always on and off looking at bits of dino films on you tube. I think because I wasn't sure if it was from a real film